# Running code-push for a React Native project on CircleCI

Tags: react-native, babeljs, circleci, code-push

We have CircleCI running a few tests in a React Native project of ours (just testing pure JS functions, not actual React Native code) — and I wanted to use code-push to push a release every time there's a successful build on master.

My problem is that code-push fails during the `react-native bundle` stage.

`react-native bundle --platform ios --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output /tmp/main.jsbundle --dev false`

The error is `TransformError: /home/ubuntu/my-project/index.ios.js: __DEV__ is not defined`

To me it seems like babel isn't successfully transforming the React Native code.

My .babelrc is:

`{
  "presets": ["react-native-stage-0"]
}`

I've tried doing things like deleting all the .babelrc files in node_modules but I still get the same error.